# Write Web Scraping Results to a .txt file

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

So I am a novice programmer who has just managed to build up his first web scraper with a lot of help from internet tutorials. The code works perfectly (sorry about the lack of comments) but it prints out everything I need onto the command window. Now I have been using the | tee example.txt function to log my results in a simple text file, but when I transfer this code to a new environment, that option is no available to me.

Getting to the point, at the end of the code I have it writing a text file to correct this but fileout.write(i.text) only grabs the last line of the data, is there a way to save all of the data gathered to a text file without having to alter the code? There probably is, and is really simple but as I said I am relatively new to this, and any advice would be greatly appreciated.

The full output of data from the web scraper is located below the code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

try:
    driver.get("http://www.caiso.com/TodaysOutlook/Pages/supply.aspx") # load the page
    WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.highcharts-legend-item.highcharts-pie-series.highcharts-color-0'))) # wait till relevant elements are on the page
except TimeoutException:
    pass
finally:
    try:
        stat_elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.highcharts-legend-item.highcharts-pie-series.highcharts-color-0')
        for el in stat_elements:
            for i in el.find_elements_by_tag_name('span'):
                print (i.text)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print ("No Such Element Found")

try:
    driver.get("http://smartgriddashboard.eirgrid.com/#all/generation") # load the page
    WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.key-stats-container > .stat-box'))) # wait till relevant elements are on the page
except TimeoutException:
    pass
finally:
    try:
        stat_elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.key-stats-container > .stat-box')
        for el in stat_elements:
            for i in el.find_elements_by_tag_name('label'):
                print(i.text)
            for i in el.find_elements_by_tag_name('p'):
                print (i.text)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print ("No Such Element Found")

filename = 'C:\Python\Scripts\data.txt'

fileout = open(filename, 'w')
fileout.write(i.text)
fileout.close()

driver.quit()

Output:

Renewables
21.8% (3,014 MW)
Solar
19.5% (860 MW)
LATEST SYSTEM
GENERATION
4,951 MW
THERMAL GENERATION
(COAL, GAS, OTHER)
76.94 %
RENEWABLE
GENERATION
20.09 %
NET
IMPORT
2.97 %
```

Comment: Your `i` only holds one element at a time. You need to save them in a list or something if you want to use them later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With what you are doing currently, the 'i' being written to the file is only going to be the last 'i' found in your loop. You could solve this 1 of 2 ways:

1. You can append all of your 'i' values as it loops to an array and then proceed to write this array to the file instead of 'i'.
2. You can place the file writing inside your loop so that each 'i' found is written to the file. If you do this, change

   ```
   fileout = open(filename, 'w')
   ```

to

```
    fileout = open(filename, 'a')
```

this will append each 'i' to the file instead of overwriting.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to see the output at the same time as you save it to a file? If not then run your program (the one that just sends its results out to `tee`) as

```
python ... > C:\Path\to\directory\data.txt
```

and the results will be saved in that file. You can then use the `type` command or similar to view it.

Comment: My issue is I am going to be running this as a Scheduled Task, not on the command line, is there a way I can use that command when creating the scheduled task?

Comment: A sneaky way would be to replace `sys.stdout` with an open file. E.g.: `_stdout = sys.stdout; sys.stdout = open('...', 'w')`.